# How do I configure automatic security updates with Laravel Forge's Scheduler?

Tags: laravel, cron, forge

Every week I ssh into my server and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

How can I use Laravel Forge scheduler to run these commands properly to install security updates?

From my understanding I would schedule a job with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

Is this correct and doing what I expect it be doing?

[image: Example of a command]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php /home/forge/default/artisan scheduled:run
```

Now in Laravel, I can see that I can add jobs in the kernel.php file eg:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade')
               ->weekly();
    }
```

Also Check link  Laravel's Scheduler docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#introduction